# Modified Template Literal Types

Tags: typescript

```
const lines = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
const linesWithA = lines.map(line => `${line}-A` as const);
const linesWithB = lines.map(line => `${line.toUpperCase()}-B` as const);
```

will give types:

```
declare const lines: readonly ["one", "two", "three"];
declare const linesWithA: ("one-A" | "two-A" | "three-A")[];
declare const linesWithB: `${string}-B`[];
```

Is it somehow possible to get a type for linesWithB as `("ONE-B" | "TWO-B" | "THREE-B")[]`? I'm getting `` ​`${string}-A`[] `` instead, becaue of the `toUpperCase` call.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=74&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSzAUwjAvDA2gcnMnAGhhygHcQiSoALAJ2QIF0YBDNUSKAbgChPo8JKgDqCWgEEMQlBAB0AW1YAHABSIUGAHwwABgBIA3huQBfALQTdbDuGgBKPgNgmIY2gCFprxSvXDtPSMTOSgQAFVlZWQ6AGF2ZFV7CysbGGdHIA)

Answer (score 3):

I can only do it with a (fairly innocuous) type assertion:

```typescript
const lines = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
type Lines = typeof lines;
type UpperLines = Uppercase<Lines[number]>[];
const linesWithA = lines.map(line => `${line}-A` as const);
const linesWithB = (lines.map(line => line.toUpperCase()) as UpperLines).map(line => `${line}-B` as const);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSzAUwjAvDA2gcnMnAGhhygHcQiSoALAJ2QIF0YBDNUSKAbgCgoAngAdkMADJJUGGIJEgAZvEkQ+s0QFUhIuhJRpMm7cHbIAPLtRYwAVwC2AI2R0mAPixM+naEr0B1BLQAgtKIegB0tqxCABShouguMAAGACQA3nEAvgC0gUlsHODQAJSeRbBxEP60AELSscoRUQ0oGIlxYVAghk4AwibRxcUFMD06ysVNMXFtyelZ2TX57DBeUKVAA)

It's also possible without the intermediary type aliases, but...I wouldn't:

```typescript
const lines = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
const linesWithA = lines.map(line => `${line}-A` as const);
const linesWithB = (lines.map(line => line.toUpperCase()) as [Uppercase<(typeof lines)[number]>]).map(line => `${line}-B` as const);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSzAUwjAvDA2gcnMnAGhhygHcQiSoALAJ2QIF0YBDNUSKAbgChPo8JKgDqCWgEEMQlBAB0AW1YAHABSIUGAHwwABgBIA3huQBfALQTdbDuGgBKPgNgmIY2gCFp64fKVqTbRlkOSgQAFVlZWQ6AGF2ZFV7extsSOi6YASAHlUoAE9okAAzYIh7LDAAVwUAIximLSZ7RRUfTXQdA2NhCw9rdhhnRyA)

Hopefully someone better at TypeScript than I can do it without the type assertion, though again, it's fairly innocuous.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `toUpperCase` just returns a `string`:

```
const test1 = 'no uppercase'.toUpperCase();
// const test1: string
```

I think the safest way to handle this issue is to create a new function `toUpperCase` with an assertion to get the proper type:

```
const toUpperCase = <S extends string>(line: S) =>
  line.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<S>

const test2 = toUpperCase('uppercase');
// const test2: "UPPERCASE"
```

If you use this function in `linesWithB`, it will have the desired return type:

```
const linesWithB = lines.map(line => `${toUpperCase(line)}-B` as const);
// const linesWithB: ("ONE-B" | "TWO-B" | "THREE-B")[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSzAUwjAvDA2gcnMnAGhhygHcQiSoALAJ2QIF0YBDNUSKAbgCgB6fjGEwAegH5evTtBhQQAVQAOS5HQDC7ZBhgAeAMoxkADyjIwAEzTQ6SAOYA+ABSIUALhj6AlBge9hrsgAdPLKqhpaTj7sMGFqwFoGftLgsmbQAIw6OGAgMACuKvFaOCGKRREQyFF8giJikilccqhQAEw6oRWaVU44heEJVThetUIiElIysIEQAOoItABCOrNBALasSi5I2ugOMAAGACQA3l3hPdWBXgC+ALRLh2wcqVCjAuPCk0A)

Update: There's a [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44268) about this, but it will (probably?) require making `String` generic, which is a rather extensive change.

Comment: Much prefer this to the answer augmenting the global types instead, though it does still require a type assertion like mine does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think that one assertion is unavoidable unless https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44268 gets implemented.

Comment: I think the consensus was that *String* would not need to be generic, you could just make [the individual methods generic](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44268#issuecomment-944037476) against the type of the `this`-argument.

Comment: @Coderer I noticed that on a second read (which prompted me to add a `(probably?)` to my update). I haven't seen a clear confirmation from any of the TypeScript members though, so I'm not entirely certain yet that it is really that easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could augment the global namespace and add an overload for the `toUpperCase` function:

```ts
declare global {
    interface String {
        toUpperCase<T extends string>(this: T): Uppercase<T>
    }
}
```

No type assertion is required:

```ts
// ("ONE-B" | "TWO-B" | "THREE-B")[]
const linesWithB = lines.map(line => `${line.toUpperCase()}-B` as const)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoeB8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgMpkymI76EdkoCqADr5QDCUAM4gAPABV4IAB4USwEfBFMWAPgAUZABZERALniSAlEb4CYYURMnr2BAL65nAelfxQkWAmTpM8AC2AK6q8GgIpPBQQSjAwRAguHK8KDBkOM64YCgkYRCkIMoAvPAA2gDkuSAVADTwFWQA7ih1DbpwNQC60co5eWQA3Nm5+YUiAOpEugCC8KUFJEUAdIFQvJqLCMXq8AAGACTYW44AtDN7vfD9qibDNxlbk9M6AELz8E+r65uF87uHY6FZZcCxCGyaExnV6XUTXUZkExAA)

Comment: Very interesting, though I worry about the knock-on effects of that global definition. The type of `y` in `const x = "testing"; const y = x.toUpperCase();` goes from being `string` to being `"TESTING"`. Hmmm...

Comment: Also, while there's no explicit type assertion, there is a type assertion. The return type of `String.prototype.toUpperCase` **is** `string`. Your added definition overloads the definition to apply a different type to it. That sounds a lot like a type assertion to me.

Comment: Interesting approach, though I share T.J. Crowders concerns.